# Add text to shapefile in specific locations

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, text

I have downloaded a grid with the latitudes and longitudes of the world but the numbers (e.g 0°, 30°, 60°, 90°) are not shown in the shapefile. Is there a way to add this text manually and then merge it with the shapefile layer?

Comment: Its a line layer?

Comment: Is it polygon or line based grid? I think you should just be able to label based on the numbers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add an attribute to the file.

For example using the Processing Toolbox and "Add field to attribute table" tool. Make sure you select String as Field type if you want the degree character °.

Then edit the lines with the text you want in the attribute column. Open the attribute table, toggle editing on, select the line you want, which will then be highlighted in the attribute table, double click on the field and type in the degree value.